# Localize an NSArray

Tags: ios, localization, nsarray

I've been localizating my app with this method:

.m file

```
... initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CONFIRMACAO_TEL", @"Message")
```

Localizable.strings file

```
"CONFIRMACAO_TEL" = "Do you want to call?";
```

The last data that I've to localize are two NSArray's and, despite all the searching, I still can't figure it out how to do it.

Here's my array:

```
descricaoServicos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test 1, test 2", @"test 3", @"test 4", nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can localize like this:

```
descricaoServicos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"test 1, test 2",@"test 1, test 2"), NSLocalizedString(@"test 3", @""), NSLocalizedString(@"test 4", @""), nil];
```

Comment: I was hoping for an easier solution because I've a huge array but works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Nikos said indirectly, you can't do it better.

But you can short it using a macro like this :

```
#define Local(str) NSLocalizedString(str, nil)
```

Your code will be a bit shorter